# A Confusion about $\sigma$-compact as a condition（In Rudin 2.17）

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image: The Theorem and Proof]

In this Theorem, I do not understand how $\sigma$-compact support the proof. I think we can simply find a sequence of open sets $V_n$ such that $\mu (V_n-E)<\frac{1}{n}$ and $E\subset V_n$ and then $V=\bigcap V_n$ satisfy $\mu (V-E)=0$. Since for every measurable set $E$, we have $\mu (E)=\inf \{\mu(V):E\subset V,V\text{ is open}\}$ in this book.

Comment: Why is $\nu (V-E)=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, what if $\mu(E)=\infty$?

You may try to write $\mu(V_{n}-E)=\mu(V_{n})-\mu(E)$ for $E\subseteq V_{n}$ but this is no longer true if $\mu(E)=\infty$.